# What is wrong with this query AND and OR Logic

Tags: sql, select, conditional-statements

```
    select [Financial Year],  cast(sum(case when [IMU Visit] = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as float) as IMU_Visits from DEO_Visits
    where TotalSchool is null and visittype='regular'
    and ((Season = 'Winter' and Month  NOT in ('January','February'))
    OR (Season = 'Summer' and Month NOT in ('July','August')))
    group by  [Financial Year]
    having sum([IMU Visit]) > 0
```

According to me, I have written the above query correctly. I want to exclude Jan and Feb months in winter and July and August months in summer but the query is not working. It returns `93762 records` weather I include the last `and .. OR`.

If i replace `Not in` but `In` only then I get some result from the query. Those are the records that I want to subtract from the result. What am I doing wrong? Spend a lot of time on this seemingly simple problem. Thanks

### Update

The following query returns result (that basically I want to exclude). I have only changed `Not in` by `In`

```
    select [Financial Year],  cast(sum(case when [IMU Visit] = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as float) as IMU_Visits from DEO_Visits
    where TotalSchool is null and visittype='regular'
    and ((Season = 'Winter' and Month  in ('January','February'))
    OR (Season = 'Summer' and Month  in ('July','August')))
    group by  [Financial Year]
    having sum([IMU Visit]) > 0
```

Comment: If you replace the `not in` with an `in` listing 10 other months, do you get the results you're seeking?

Comment: when I replace `not in` by `in` i do get results, in that case the query works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic looks correct to me.  I don't see why you are converting `Visits` to a `float` however:

```
select [Financial Year],
       sum(case when [Visit] = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Visits
from Visits
where TotalSchool is null and
      visittype = 'regular' and
      ((Season = 'Winter' and Month not in ('January', 'February')) or
       (Season = 'Summer' and Month not in ('July', 'August'))
      )
group by [Financial Year]
having sum([Visit]) > 0;
```

One possibility is the spelling of the months.  If the months are `'Jan'`, `'Feb'`, etc, then the `not in` will always pass.

Comment: Note that `and ((Season = 'Winter' and Month  in ('January','February'))
  OR (Season = 'Summer' and Month  in ('July','August')))` returns certain number of rows where I basically changed 'Not in' to 'In' only. Those are the rows that I want to remove.

Comment: ran this query. Same result. Does not change anything.

Comment: @hmd . . . I explained that in the answer.  I think the reason is because the values in the `not in` list don't match actual values in the data, but I don't know what those values really are.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it from the logic like this:

`(A and B) or (C and D)`

Where

- A --> Season = 'Winter'
- B --> Month in ('January','February')
- C --> Season = 'Summer'
- D --> Month in ('July','August')

What you want is the opposite of the condition above. In other words

`not ((A and B) or (C and D))`

Using De Morgan's law (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence), you can change it to Hamlet's suggestion

`not (A and B) and not (C and D)`

You can apply De Morgan's law once more to make it

`(not A or not B) and (not C or not D)`

Therefore, you can also write the following condition

```
(Season <> 'Winter' or Month  not in ('January','February'))
and (Season <> 'Summer' or Month not in ('July','August'))
```

Or the easiest way is to simply add NOT on your condition. Frankly, I'd go with this one as it's probably the easiest to understand if you go back and re-read your SQL query.

Comment: This give me the same result as `and 
      ((Season = 'Winter' and Month  in ('January', 'February')) or
       (Season = 'Summer' and Month  in ('July', 'August'))
      )`. Which I dont want. I want to exclude  Jan, Feb for winter schools and July,Aug for summer schools. I should be able to count the rest of the months.

Comment: I added another option. Just add NOT on your condition if that's what you want to exclude. That's probably the easiest way. `and NOT ((Season = 'Winter' and Month in ('January', 'February')) or (Season = 'Summer' and Month in ('July', 'August')) )`

Comment: I tried the last query but it does not affect the query at all

Comment: There must be something else then. I find it hard to believe that `and (something)` has the same result as `and not (something)`. Any other info that you may add?

Answer (score 0):

AND((Season = 'Winter' and Month not in ('January','February'))
AND(Season = 'Summer' and Month not in ('July','August')))

Comment: Changing the `OR` to an `AND`? You think you'll find any rows where `Season` is simultaneously equal to both `Winter` and `Summer`?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
 select [Financial Year],  cast(sum(case when [IMU Visit] = 1 then 1 else 0  end) as float) as IMU_Visits from DEO_Visits
 where TotalSchool is null and visittype='regular' group by  [Financial Year]
 having sum([IMU Visit]) > 0
 MINUS
 select [Financial Year],  cast(sum(case when [IMU Visit] = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as float) as IMU_Visits from DEO_Visits
 where TotalSchool is null and visittype='regular'
 and ((Season = 'Winter' and Month  in ('January','February'))
 OR (Season = 'Summer' and Month  in ('July','August')))
 group by  [Financial Year]
 having sum([IMU Visit]) > 0
```

I know it's not optimized in any way but as you explained that the query works fine when you use 'in' and you want to substract those results, the above query should work.